# C++ Windows _pclose return value: _cwait needed?

Tags: c++, windows, pipe, pclose

I want to get the exit status of a pipe in C++, both on Linux and on Windows, to check whether a command ran successfully.

On Linux (or POSIX more generally), it appears that the macros in `<sys/wait.h>` are needed to get the correct exit status, such as in the first answer to the question

[Does pclose() return pipe's termination status shifted left by eight bits on all platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27453248/11770674)

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #define popen _popen
    #define pclose _pclose
#else
    #include <sys/wait.h>
#endif

int main(){
    FILE* pipe {nullptr};
    pipe = popen( "echo 123", "r" );

    int status {0};
    status = pclose(pipe);

    #ifndef _WIN32
    /* ask how the process ended to clean up the exit code. */
    if ( WIFEXITED(status) ){
        /* Add code here if needed after pipe exited normally */
        status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    } else if ( WIFSIGNALED(status) ){
        /* Add code here if needed after pipe process was terminated */
        status = WTERMSIG(status);
    } else if ( WIFSTOPPED(status) ){
        /* Add code here if needed after pipe stopped  */
        status = WSTOPSIG(status);
    }
    #else
    /* but what about windows? */
    #endif

    std::cout << "Exit status: " << status << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find anything about Windows though. The [C runtime lib reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pclose) for `_pclose` includes a remark about [`_cwait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cwait) and states that

"The format of the return value [of `_pclose`] is the same as for `_cwait`, except the low-order and high-order bytes are swapped".

So how do I get the correct exit status on Windows?

Comment: Don't spam C tag if your code is C++

Comment: The code is using the C runtime library, and the topic is *exactly* as relevant to C. People who watch the C tag have the same or possibly a higher chance of being able to answer the question. Therefore, I find the tag appropriate.

Comment: How about a helpful comment or reply instead?